# ROS2: communication over two machines on the same network

Tags: ros, ros2, communication, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I am experiencing a weird problem with ROS2 foxy. Basically I have one machine that is not able to commuinate over ROS2 with others on the same network.

Let me give you some details:

MACHINE 1 (the one with the problem)
Laptop DELL
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
ROS2 Foxy

MACHINE 2 (this one is able to communicate with others in the same network but not with MACHINE 1)
Laptop DELL
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
ROS2 Foxy

Machine 1 cannot discover topic being published, and if it publish I cannot see the topics being published on Machine2(or any other machine)

I am able to ping M1 from M2 and viceversa, ROS_DOMAIN_ID is not set and even if I set it, that does not solve the problem.
I would exclude that the porblem is because of the mismatch of two OS, in fact I have other machines with Ubuntu 20.024 able to communicate over ros topics.

Anybody has any clue on what's going on here?

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall ROS, that did not fix the issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387192/ros2:-communication-over-two-machines-on-the-same-network/) by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2021-09-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-23**:
Can you please! provide all steps you have followed. Thanks

**Comment by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on 2021-09-23**:
I am not sure what do you mean with all the steps I have followed. I publish a topic with ros2 topic pub /topicXYZ msg_type (e.g. ros2 topic pub /asdfg nav_msgs/msg/Path) and on the other machine I use ros2 topic echo /topicXYZ (e.g. ros2 topic echo /asdfg)

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-23**:
I was telling you about configuration steps, Do you have /topicXYZ msg file in other machines? If no then I would suggest to add the following msg file and build a package and try.

**Comment by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on 2021-09-23**:
That message type is installed in both machines

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-23**:
Main Pc:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://url:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.1
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1
```

Second Pc:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311/    # Ip address of 1 PC
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.2
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2
```

This was my configuration while connecting 2 PC.

You have to include this in your bashrc file.

**Comment by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on 2021-09-23**:
Thank you for your support and time but the problem was the firewall, sudo ufw disable solved the issue

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-23**:
make it an answer and tick it.

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2021-09-23**:
ROS2 does not use any of those environment variables to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out to be a firewall issue.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

made the magic

---

Originally posted by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) with karma: 71 on 2021-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1